# Unable to to import modules from peer libraries in an Angular monorepo

Tags: angular, npm, lerna

**Context**

We have a monorepo Angular UI component library and we are trying to introduce Lerna 6.

**The Problem**
Compilation failure trying to build one of the libraries which has a dependency on a peer library of the monorepo.

```
✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
src/lib/components/gauge/gauge.component.ts:13:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ui-lib/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

We are using:

- Lerna 6
- Angular 13
- npm 8

And to note we are using npm workspaces.

**The project structure**

Reduced for brevity.

```
|-projects
|---ui-lib
   |---core
       |----ng-package.json
       |----package.json
       |----tsconfig.lib.json
   |---charts
       |----ng-package.json
       |----package.json
       |----tsconfig.lib.json
|-angular.json
|-package.json
|-dist
  |---ui-lib
     |---core
```

Snippet of charts package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@ui-lib/core": "file:../core",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0"
}
```

Snippet of root package.json

```
"workspaces": [
    "./projects/ui-lib/*"
]
```

Snippet of lerna.json

```
{
    "$schema": "node_modules/lerna/schemas/lerna-schema.json",
    "version": "independent",
    "useWorkspaces": true,
    "workspaces" : [
        "projects/ui-lib/*"
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.lib.json for charts library

```
{
    "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../../../out-tsc/lib",
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "types": [],
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015"
        ]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
        "strictMetadataEmit": true,
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "flatModuleId": "AUTOGENERATED",
        "flatModuleOutFile": "AUTOGENERATED"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "src/test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

A component in the charts lib imports a module like so:

```
import {isNullOrUndefined} from '@ui-lib/core';
```

This is where the compilation issue occurs.

My background is more server side so I am not an advanced user of npm or Angular but I am struggling to find in the docs of these tools where we have gone wrong in establishing the dependency between the libararies.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: you didn't show it here but make sure that your core package also has a `"name": "@ui-lib/core"` in its `package.json`. However I'm guessing your problem is around `file:../core`, you should use the version as the package you are pointing to, like `"@ui-lib/core": "^1.0.0"`

Answer (score 0):

The solution for us was actually updating the root `tsconfig.json` file `paths` to target the `dist` of each library. Each library's own `tsconfig.lib.json` file extends the root `tsconfig.json` file.

Snippet of the root `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "./node_modules/@angular/*"
      ],
      "@ui-lib/core": [
        "projects/ui-lib/core/dist"
      ]
}
```

We added a path for each library that had a peer dependency for compilation.